# Elm Language viewInput text new line

Tags: elm

I am new to to Elm.  I would like to have each viewInput text box on a new line.

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ viewInput "text" "Address" model.address Address
    , viewInput "text" "Address2" model.address2 Address2 
    , viewInput "text" "City" model.city City
    , viewInput "text" "State" model.state State
    , viewInput "text" "Zipcode" model.zipcode Zipcode
```

I have tried to use the break tag but can't seem to figure it out and the error messages are not helping.

Thank  you

Comment: Could you show the implementation of viewInput function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `input` is an inline element by [default](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp), you need to wrap it in a block element to display it on a separate line. `div` tag can be used:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div [] [ viewInput "text" "Address" model.address Address ]
        , div [] [ viewInput "text" "Address2" model.address2 Address2 ]
        , div [] [ viewInput "text" "City" model.city City ]
        , div [] [ viewInput "text" "State" model.state State ]
        , div [] [ viewInput "text" "Zipcode" model.zipcode Zipcode ]
        ]
```

Or just put this `div` tag in `viewInput` implementation.

Another option is to change it via `CSS`.

Comment: Thank you Igor very elegant.  Are you an Elm programmer?

Answer (score 2):

use the break tag like this

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ viewInput "text" "Address" model.address Address
    , br [] []
    , viewInput "text" "Address2" model.address2 Address2 
    , br [] []
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you Erik for your reply.  Very helpful.  Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could change `viewInput` to return `List (Html Msg)`, and then include `br [] []` in returned list:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    viewInput "text" "Address" model.address Address
    ++ viewInput "text" "Address2" model.address2 Address2 
    ++ viewInput "text" "City" model.city City
    ++ viewInput "text" "State" model.state State
    ++ viewInput "text" "Zipcode" model.zipcode Zipcode
  ]

viewInput: ... -> List (Html Msg)
viewInput ... =
  [ ...
  , br [] []
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you Marcus for your time and answer.  Very helpful.